# jquery form success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with some filters, I submit it with jquery ajax and not return anything on success, it simply stops there. I tried whit dataType='html', json, text ... and nothing.

my datastring var is something like "select-prod=5&order-prod=0", so i think it's ok

Here is the code

```
<script>   
    $(function(){

        $("#filtros").submit(function(){

            var url = "submit.php"; 
            var cargando = document.getElementById("cargando");
            var content  = document.getElementById("contenido_productos");
            var datastring = $("#filtros").serialize();

            content.style.display='none';
            cargando.style.display='block';
            $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: url,
                       data: datastring,
                       success: function(data){
                            cargando.style.display='none';
                            $("#contenido_productos").html(data);
                            content.style.display='block';
                       }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
    $('div#contenedor select, input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() { $("#filtros").trigger('submit'); })
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you receiving Status 200 from your server-side?

Comment: I don't know where i look that ... I am new at this haha, the only thing i can tell is that i use other script exactly like that to register users and it works fine

Comment: Check your Developer Tools, check what's coming up from submit.php

Comment: You need to double check which arguments submit.php need.

Comment: my submit.php is working fine, i check with another script php that simply had to return a "1" and not processed either

Comment: On the other script what is your data variable? 
Check if there is differences between these.

Comment: finally, the problem was on the server side, i don't know exactly why but magically now its working ...

thanks